# libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file python error while running CGIusing cx_Oracle

Tags: python, apache, cx-oracle

Need help from someone who has got Apache , Python and cx_Oracle (Lib to run Oracle database using python) .
Even after setting all the required variables still getting the error ": libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" when running python script .

The same script works perfectly fine when running it from cli.

My working environment is RHEL 6.4

An help in this matter would be appreciated , for those who got this  working in their environment

Merci d'avance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with the help of mod_env module of python by natively passing the env_variables to apache . What I did to achieve this was

--> define the my required env variables in the file /etc/sysconfig/httpd like 
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/folder_with_library/
     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

--> Then passing this variable in the httpd.conf file like 
     PassEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH needs to be set in the Apache environment.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/env.html

You can avoid dealing with this, however, by the following steps:

```
export FORCE_RPATH=1
python setup.py build
```

This is done automatically for you if you use the instant client RPMs which is an even easier method!